# Expected X-Hub-Signature via SHA1 not same as what FB is sending (code in C#)

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api, sha1

I am having problems getting the X-Hub-Signature sent to me by facebook to match the one I am generating in C#.  For a while I thought I was running the function wrong but I have now used multiple code sources on Stack Overflow and a website (http://billatnapier.com/security01.aspx) to confirm I am indeed creating the SHA-1 correctly.

So .... something is clearly wrong with the content.  I am using ASP.NET Web API and the "Payload" that I am using to feed into the SHA-1 algorithm is the JSON object I am receiving from facebook, converted to a string.  I assume this is what they want me to use when they say "Payload" is that correct?
It is a string that begins with {"entry":[   and ends with "object":"page"}

I feel like I've tried everything and have hit a brick wall so hoping someone can help me.  Web API is a bit off - even grabbing the X-Hub-Signature was a challenge as you can't just use Request.Header["X-Hub-Signature"]; I am almost wondering if I should switch back to pure MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I am answering my own question! The problem with the "Payload" is that you can't simply grab the JSON object. You have to find a way to access the Request object from Web API and then read in the payload like this:

```
var context = Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper; 

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream)) 
{ 
payload = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
}
```

It looks like binning Web API and just doing this in MVC would be easier as you then just do this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
{
    PayLoad = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```